# How to quickly see activity

Tags: discussion

It seems there has been a new UI incorporated into all of the StackExchange sites recently.

In the past, I could hover my cursor over my reputation number I believe, and it would drop down an overlay showing activity over the last day, week, and month.  That doesn't seem to work anymore.  Any reason it was deleted?

Comment: If it was reputation history you're thinking of was it similar to the new achievements button that is the third one along and looks like a bar chart displayed on an LCD with a few dead pixels?

Comment: No, this was more in a spreadsheet format, with columns for today, this week, and this month, and rows for rep earned, votes, and I can't remember the bottom two.   The new achievement button does display reputation earned, but it does not include the totals like the old one did.  That was very useful.

Comment: +1. I don't always agree to the UI changes which are applied from time to time. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it!"

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why the designer changed things, but it's there. Now it's an icon at the left end of the top black bar, looking like a group of uneven-length gray pencils, just right of what looks like a gray purse.  Sometimes it's a green box with a number e.g. "+10" instead of the pencils - this means you've gotten upvoted recently, since last time you checked.

Comment: Note you have to click the icon not just hover on it.